# Equal height text boxes and buttons

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a text field and a button appear like they are part of a joint element, so that they look like this (screenshot from Chrome Linux):

[image: Example in Chrome]

However in Firefox Linux the button is two pixels too tall:

[image: Example in Firefox]

Example CSS: http://dabblet.com/gist/1603701

I have set the font size of both elements to 16px in the hope that they will display the same, giving a line-height of 19px - but in Firefox the button has a height of 21px instead! Setting an explicit height can lead the vertical alignment to become incorrect in Firefox unless I shrink the font (not sure why that is).

Apparently you can't set the line-height on inputs in Firefox (see [article](http://www.cssnewbie.com/input-button-line-height-bug/) and [bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=349259)), so how else can I force the elements to be the right height?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a cross-browser solution:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
       <style>
            html, body{
                padding: 50px;
            }
            .inputWrapper{
                display:inline-block;
                font-size:16px;
                padding:0px;
                border:1px solid #000000;
                border-radius:6px;
                background-color:#ffffff;
            }
            .email{
                margin:0px;
                margin-left:1px;
                padding:5px;
                border-width:0px;
                border-radius: 6px 0px 0px 6px;
            }
            .submit{
                margin: -1px;
                margin-left: -5px;
                padding: 6px;
                border-width:0px;
                border-radius: 0px 6px 6px 0px;
                color:#ffffff;
                background-color:#D94E35;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="inputWrapper">
            <input class="email" type="email" value="" placeholder="email address"/>
            <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Subscribe" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can see it working here:  http://dabblet.com/gist/1604595

Comment: Looks promising, I'll do some full testing tonight and accept it if it all goes well!

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about dabblet! Awesome tool!

Answer (score 0):

you have two different paddings on your form boxes, very easy fix.

Change your CSS from this >

```
input[type="submit"] {
margin: 0;
padding: 6px 15px; /* Padding set 1px to high, so your getting 2px total extra space */
border: none;
border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
font-size: 16px;
line-height: normal;
color: white;
background: #D94E35;
}
```

To This >

```
input[type="submit"] {
margin: 0;
padding: 5px 15px; /* Now you should have even paddings */
border: none;
border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
font-size: 16px;
line-height: normal;
color: white;
background: #D94E35;
}
```

Comment: Nope, the extra padding on the submit button is to account for the lack of border.